# compile c++ wxWidgets using Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, wxwidgets

I've downloaded wxWidgets package using Cygwin setup-x86_64 and NOT from wxWidgets site.

I tried to compile the code from this site:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_helloworld.html

Still, I am receiving these errors

> fatal error: 'wx/wxprec.h' file not found
>
> fatal error: 'wx/wx.h' file

What should I do to get this package to work?

Comment: there are precompiled libraries on the official download site of wxWidgets.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [list of files](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86/mingw64-x86_64-wxWidgets3.0/mingw64-x86_64-wxWidgets3.0-3.0.2.0-3) in the package, it seems that only `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/wx-config-3.0` is being installed by this package and not `wx-config` itself (unless it's created dynamically during installation?). If this is indeed the case, you will need to use `wx-config-3.0 --cxxflags` etc on your command line to compile using it.

Notice that you also need to use MinGW cross-compiler, i.e. `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++`, depending on your target architecture, and not Cygwin `g++`.

Comment: the x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ compiler gives me info that wx-config-3.0: No such file or directory although I've found this .o file. also it doesn't seem to recognise '--cxxflags' for some reason. is it a library path issue?

Comment: I assume that you either use the full path or added `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin` to your `PATH`, otherwise it doesn't risk to be found...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the wx-config flags?

```
g++ $(wx-config --cxxflags) -o out *.cpp $(wx-config --libs)
```

Comment: I have tried but I receive an info -bash :wx-config: command not found.
is this a catalogue with necessary .h files or sth?

Comment: It seems to not be installed then. You can find the installer for windows 
[here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Wx-Config).

And the explanation of its utility and the commands
[here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Wx-Config).

Note that the command I provided to you are in that last page too, though be it written with backticks.

I hope that solves the problem.

Comment: You mean the wx-config Windows port on the bottom of the page? According to the download page I'll have to set up the path to the place where I downloaded the wxWidgets itself.
Correct? BTW I've just found out that this port was NOT found on the server

Comment: @Gulzt, he is using some Cygwin-baked binaries which is neither Windows, nor Linux. It is not known to the community. ;-) The best bet is to compile everything yourself with MinGW and use the appropriate command to compile the OFFICIAL samples.